# Opening another viewcontroller when clicking on cell of collectionview

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I am new to swift, I followed this video to do a Collection view and it is working perfectly. But on clicking from one cell to another on clicking is not working.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQOhsyWUhwg

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
  didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Cell \(indexPath.row + 1) clicked")
  }
```

Here it is printing the cell which is selected. I just need to open another view when the cell is clicked. Can anybody help me.

Comment: "I just need to open another view when the cell is clicked"  What does opening another view mean?  Transioning to a different view controller?

Comment: Yes another view controller .. Sorry

Comment: Help youself by running a search.  There are a ton of similar topics that are waiting for you.

Answer (score 1):

Let's guess the viewController you want to navigate is `SecondViewController`. And Storyboard name is `Main`.

To navigate a ViewController

1. You need to create an instance of that ViewController
2. You need to push that viewController from Navigation Controller

```swift
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    
}

var secondViewController: SecondViewController {
    let st = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = st.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
    return vc
}
```

Now if you want to navigate viewcontroller from cell tap. Just push that viewcontroller into your navigation stack.

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
  didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Cell \(indexPath.row + 1) clicked")
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create object of the another view controller and push it.
like :

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "your_view_identifier") as! Your_ViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
```